# Can't connect to www.google.com and google related websites on Mac. Other websites like YouTube, Facebook, are OK

Tags: macos

Can't connect to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and google related websites on Mac. Other websites like YouTube, Facebook, are OK.

And report the following error:

[image: The error message of failing]

Comment: GIve more information. Like what means of internet are you using? And did you just installed macOS? etc.

Comment: I have used macOS for a long time and this issue just happed recently. I have tried safari and chrome, which didn't work.

Comment: Ok. Now it looks like its DNS problem. Try changing DNS to `8.8.8.8`

Comment: Thanks! It's working now.@thisisjaymehta

Comment: Cool. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

After changing my MAC's DNS number. The problem is resolved.

Method as following:

[https://www.howtogeek.com/167533/the-ultimate-guide-to-changing-your-dns-server/#:~:text=To%20change%20your%20DNS%20server%2C%20head%20to%20Settings,check%20an%20“Advanced”%20box%20to%20see%20this%20setting.](https://www.howtogeek.com/167533/the-ultimate-guide-to-changing-your-dns-server/#:%7E:text=To%20change%20your%20DNS%20server%2C%20head%20to%20Settings,check%20an%20%E2%80%9CAdvanced%E2%80%9D%20box%20to%20see%20this%20setting.)